# How can I modify this scatterplot to include a hierarchy based on a 3rd column of data?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatterplot of PM2.5 against life expectancy, within this i want 5 subcategories based on the GDP data (5 different colour plots and lines based on High to low GDP). How would i modify my current code to do this (or similar)? Code and data below, any help much appreciated.

```
plot = ggplot(dat6, aes(x=log(PM2.5), y= log(Lifeex))) +
  geom_point(colour = 'blue') +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") + 
  xlab("Life Expectancy") +
  ylab("Concentration of PM2.5") +
  ggtitle("Relationship between Life expectancy and PM2.5")



dat6
                 Country Life_Expectancy         GDP     PM2.5
1                Afghanistan        60.38333   1788.3152 53.933333
2                    Albania        77.03333  10642.3801 20.408333
3                    Algeria        75.16667  13674.2199 31.521667
4                     Angola        51.96667   6770.9149 37.346667
5        Antigua and Barbuda        75.98333  20893.5925 20.415000
6                  Argentina        75.93333  19838.7166 11.893333
7                    Armenia        74.26667   7728.3425 33.143333
8                  Australia        82.36667  43862.4894  7.338333
9                    Austria        84.00000  46586.1927 14.303333
10                Azerbaijan        72.00000  16804.9607 20.308333
```

Comment: Can you define high to low GDP in the question, please? This seems a job for `?cut`. Or `?findInterval`.

Comment: I'm looking to break GDP into 5 equal categories from highest to lowest. So from the data above I'd have >40,000, 40,000-20,000, 19,999-10,000, 9,999,-5000 and 4,999-0. Is this something that i need to do before or is it something that can be done whilst building the plot? In short im trying to make scatter plots by potential hierarchies. Hope thats helpful, cheers.

Comment: It's something you have to do before plotting. And with `cut` you can assign labels to the groups, say `"very high"`, `"high"`, `"medium"`, etc. Or any others.

Comment: Do you mind be asking for a quick example? not a function that im familiar with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what the question asks for.

`cut` is used to create a new column `GDP_Level` based on a break points vector `brks`. The levels are assigned names, ranging from `"Very Low"` to `"Very High"`.

As for the plot I have removed the `log` transformations from the coordinates code and included then as transformations in both `scale_*continuous` instead.

```r
dat6 <- read.table(text = "
                 Country Life_Expectancy         GDP     PM2.5
1                Afghanistan        60.38333   1788.3152 53.933333
2                    Albania        77.03333  10642.3801 20.408333
3                    Algeria        75.16667  13674.2199 31.521667
4                     Angola        51.96667   6770.9149 37.346667
5        'Antigua and Barbuda'        75.98333  20893.5925 20.415000
6                  Argentina        75.93333  19838.7166 11.893333
7                    Armenia        74.26667   7728.3425 33.143333
8                  Australia        82.36667  43862.4894  7.338333
9                    Austria        84.00000  46586.1927 14.303333
10                Azerbaijan        72.00000  16804.9607 20.308333
", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

brks <- c(0, 5000, 10000, 20000, 40000, Inf)
dat6$GDP_Level <- cut(dat6$GDP, breaks = brks, labels = c("Very Low", "Low", "Medium", "High", "Very High"))

ggplot(dat6, aes(x = PM2.5, y = Life_Expectancy, color = GDP_Level)) +
  geom_point(colour = 'blue') +
  stat_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm", col = "red") + 
  xlab("Life Expectancy") +
  ylab("Concentration of PM2.5") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log") +
  ggtitle("Relationship between Life expectancy and PM2.5")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is brilliant, can't thank you enough for the help.